# TypeError: formik.getFieldProps is not a function

Tags: reactjs, next.js, formik

I've included a Field component to useFormik on my Nextjs app, and now this error message is showing up:

```
Server Error
TypeError: formik.getFieldProps is not a function
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
../../pages/_document.tsx (91:33) @ Function.getInitialProps
  89 |     }
  90 | 
> 91 |     const { html, head } = await ctx.renderPage({ enhanceApp })
     |                                 ^
  92 |     const styles = [...flush()]
  93 |     return { html, head, styles }
  94 |   }
```

Console shows the same error message:

```
TypeError: formik.getFieldProps is not a function
```

The form worked fine before, but I'm trying to add the radio buttons.

This is the new code that was added that introduced the problem:

```
const RadioButtons = (props) => {
  const {
    label, name, options, ...rest
  } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <label>{label}</label>
      <Field name={name} {...rest}>
        {
          ({ field }) => options.map((options) => (
            <React.Fragment key={option.key}>
              <input
                type="radio"
                id={option.value}
                {...field}
                value={option.value}
                checked={field.value === option.value}
              />
              <label htmlFor={option.value}>{option.key}</label>
            </React.Fragment>
          ))
        }
      </Field>
      <ErrorMessage name={name} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Used here:

```
const Footer = () => {
  const radioOptions = [
    { key: 'Option 1', value: 'Investor Interest' },
    { key: 'Option 2', value: 'Leasing Interest' },
  ];

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      fullname: '',
      company: '',
      email: '',
      interest: '',
    },
    validationSchema: Yup.object({
      fullname: Yup.string()
        .max(50, 'Must be 50 characters or less')
        .required('Required'),
      company: Yup.string()
        .max(50, 'Must be 50 characters or less')
        .required('Required'),
      email: Yup.string().email('Invalid email address')
        .required('Required'),
      interest: Yup.string().required('Required'),
    }),
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    },
  });

  return (
  etc...
  <RadioButtons
    label="Some label here"
    name="interest"
    options={radioOptions}
  />
  )
```

Is it because I'm adding them in Nextjs, due to SSR? I feel like the code is correct, so I'm not sure what is 'cause the issue here.

I've also posted this question [here](https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/2821), but I'm not sure that I'll get a response quickly there.

Comment: Ever get to the bottom of this? I have the same error.

Comment: @Sarcoma No, I ended up using React-hook-form instead :/

Comment: Oh no, lol. I'll see what I can find out, cheers.